# How to load a filechooser dialog

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am a Kivy newbie and despite having read a couple of books, a fair amount of the Kivy documentation, and looked at numerous examples, I'm still having great trouble at working out how to structure my program. I'm trying to get a filechooser dialog working.

I want to start with a simple BoxLayout interface with a single button. On pressing this button I want to display the filechooser dialog. I've taken a lot of this code from one of the books. My problem is how to invoke the LoadDialog widget/class. I know that my button shouldn't refer to root.show_load_list() but I'm not sure how I should refer to it. I'd be most grateful for a nudge in the right direction.

```
# File name: main.py
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder


class LoadDialog(FloatLayout):
    load = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)

    def show_load_list(self):
        content = LoadDialog(load=self.load_list, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Load a file list", content=content, size_hint=(1, 1))
        self._popup.open()

    def load_list(self, path, filename):
        pass

    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()

class LoadDialogApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LoadDialogApp().run()
```

My kv file is defined as

```
# File name: loaddialog.kv

BoxLayout:
    Button:
        text: "Click me"
        on_release: root.show_load_list()

<LoadDialog>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser
            path: './'
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()
            Button:
                text: "Load"
                on_release: root.load(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Python Code

1. Add missing import statement, `from kivy.uix.popup import Popup`
2. Rename class `LoadDialog` to `Root`
3. Add a class LoadDialog with just two ObjectProperty

### Snippet

```
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup


class LoadDialog(FloatLayout):
    load = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)


class Root(FloatLayout):
    load = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)

    def show_load_list(self):
```

## kv file

1. Add root rule, `Root:` before `BoxLayout:`

### Snippet

```
Root:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Click me"
            on_release: root.show_load_list()

<LoadDialog>:
    BoxLayout:
```

## Output

[image: Img01]